# Написать функцию sum(), которая будет работать как калькулятор

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решается такая задача. (*из сборника задач на собеседование)
Написать функцию sum(), которая будет работать как калькулятор

```
sum(1)() // 1
sum(1)(2)() // 3
sum(1)(2)(-1)() // 2
```

Для меня как бы очень смутил такой вариант вызова.

Comment: Уж не рекурсию ли от Вас просят...

Comment: Где-то видел подобные вопросы..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Функция должна анализировать передаваемое значение и, если аргумент задан, возвращать новую функцию или, если передан `undefined`, возвращать результат

```js
function sum(arg, res) {
  if (arg === undefined)
    return res;
  res = (res || 0) + arg;
  return function(arg) {
    return sum(arg, res);
  }
}

console.log(sum(1)()); // 1
console.log(sum(1)(2)()); // 3
console.log(sum(1)(2)(-1)()); // 2
```

Даже, во избежание ошибок, можно сделать функцию с одним аргументом

```js
function sum(arg) {
  const localSum = function(arg, res) {
    if (arg === undefined)
      return res;
    res = (res || 0) + arg;
    return function(arg) {
      return localSum(arg, res);
    }
  }
  return localSum(arg);
}

console.log(sum(1)()); // 1
console.log(sum(1)(2)()); // 3
console.log(sum(1)(2)(-1)()); // 2
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function sum(arg, res = 0) {
    return (arg === undefined) ? res : arg2 => sum(arg2, res + arg);
}

console.log(sum(1)()); // 1
console.log(sum(1)(2)()); // 3
console.log(sum(1)(2)(-1)()); // 2
```

еще более короткая запись

```
sum = (arg, res = 0) => arg === undefined ? res : arg2 => sum(arg2, res + arg);
```

Пояснение:

1. объявляем функцию как лямбда выражение, содержащее аргументы (в круглых скобках) - `arg` - значение, с которым надо сложить полученный ранее результат, `res` - полученный ранее результат, и тело функции после символа `=>`, если тело занимает одну строчку, то не надо делать `return` и писать фигурные скобки

   ```
    sum = (arg, res = 0) =>
   ```
2. второй аргумент `res` (накопленный ранее результат) по умолчанию равен 0, т.е. если функция вызывается без второго аргумента, то он автоматически считается равным значению, указанному в скобках (т.е. в данном случае 0)
3. основной алгоритм такой - если `arg` не определён, т.е. вызвана функция `sum()`, то возвращается накопленный ранее результат `res`, иначе возвращается функция с накопленным ранее результатом
4. в качестве функции с накопленным значением опять возвращаем лямбда-выражение

   ```
    arg2 => sum(arg2, res + arg)
   ```

т.е. безымянную функцию у которой аргумент arg2, а тело - возврат значения функции `sum` в которой накоплен результат предыдущих вызовов `res + arg`

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @aleksandr barakin, выполнено :)